# Numpy: how to calculate log without warning?

Tags: python, numpy

I just upgrade to a new version of Anaconda, in which

```
%matplotlib inline

from numpy import inf, arange, array, linspace, exp, log, power, pi, cos, sin, radians, degrees
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = linspace(0, 10)
plt.plot(x, log(x),'o', label='ECDF')
```

works fine, but will return the warning

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
```

Surely, the problem is that I use `x = linspace(0, 10)`, which start at 0, and then pass it to `log(x)`. But the problem is that, how can I refactor my code, so the warning disapears?

Generally speaking, most plot always start with 0. something like `x = linspace(0.00000001, 10)` looks very ugly to me.

Comment: Have a look at this documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html

Comment: "most plot always start with 0." Well, this one certainly shouldn't...

Answer (score 3):

Numpy offers a nice mechanism to suppress warnings using `errstate`, which applies only locally when used with `with`.

```
with np.errstate(divide = 'ignore'):
    plt.plot(x, np.log(x),'o', label='ECDF')
```

However, I would recommend this approach only if you are unable to "manually" modify your code to avoid the warning.

Comment: Tried several alternatives including `log(x, where)` but this was exactly what I was looking for: Identical behaviour, but no warning.

Answer (score 2):

Logarithm is not defined in 0, so you can not possibly plot a graph for that function at zero. One option I see is that instead of plotting log(x) you plot a bit more complex function:

```
lambda x: log(x) if x > 0 else 0
```

Of course you could choose a different value for x = 0 but I think `0` makes sense.

Using the parameters of `linspace` it is possible to exclude the last point(by using `x = linspace(0, 10, endpoint=False)`) but I don't think there is a way to exclude the starting point.